# Is it common to have RESTful endpoint returning Protobuf strings?

Tags: api, rest, protocol-buffers, grpc

Instead of having a gRPC server (say, due to platform restrictions), you have a REST endpoint that returns `data.SerializeToString()` as the payload. Of course, any clients of this endpoint would have the appropriate proto files for each response, so they can `ParseFromString(data)` and be on their way. Reasons for doing this includes the benefits of Protobufs.

Comment: Clarification needed. If REST server is an option for you, does it mean that RPC is not essential? PB is just a binary serialization format. You can attach a base64 of it to email if you want. But it won't give you RPC. Using PB for other purposes than RPC payloads is not an antipattern, but simulating RPC over REST is an antipattern.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm trying to simulate rpc. Just wanting to send structured data over the wire.

Comment: Well, you tagged the question with `grpc`. Then gRPC server is redundant. Use the base PB Builders (a code generated by `protoc` in most languages) which give a serialization to byte array or byte stream. Set up a plain http server, and assign the bytes to http response body. What's your language? I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Server is python and the clients using it are python, node, and go. My question is if this is common. Not sure I see it as an antipattern at all. Since speed is a very critical part of said API, the overhead of json serialization is not negligible in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improved understanding of the question: is it common to use PBs for other purposes than gRPC transport?

Yes it is totally common and reasonable. PBs are really nothing more than a data serialization format. gRPC just uses it as message interchange format (natural choice as both are Google creations). Let the answer be the description from Google itself:

> Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data.

[Google's basic tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#writing-a-message) is saving it to disk. Do anything you would do with any other binary blob (jpeg, mp3, ...)

**BUT!** if serialization speed is really critical for you, don't assume anything. Today's JSON libs may be unexpectedly well performing - depends on your specific platforms and dominant message characteristics. Do your own performance tests. If JSON inferiority is confirmed, then there are again libs with faster serialization than PB. To name a couple: Google's less popular PB sibling [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) and something called [Simple Binary Encoding](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2014/05/simple-binary-encoding.html), which was developed for High Frequency Trading... speaks for itself.